# Implementing large data set causing "string index out of range" error in Python?

Tags: python, string, file, bioinformatics

I am trying to implement the following code:

```
with open('datapath') as f:
   k_mers = f.read()

k_mers_parsed = []

for i in k_mers.split('\n'):
   k_mers_parsed.append(i)
genome = k_mers_parsed[0]
for i in range(1,len(k_mers_parsed)):
   genome = genome + k_mers_parsed[i][-1]

with open('filepath', 'w') as out:
out.write(genome)
```

Reading a file that has about 4 lines of code works perfectly and I generate the solution set needed in a quick manner.

However, whenever I try to import a large scale dataset, one with say, 1000 lines, I get this error:

```
genome = genome + k_mers_parsed[i][-1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What is the root cause of this and how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have an empty line in the file.
Also try this:

```
with open('datapath') as f:
    genome = [l[-1] for l in f if l]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not because of reading 1000 lines .It is because there are no data in some lines

**i.e.)**

```
st="""
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: asd
    ...: """

print st
'\n\n\nasd\n'

lst=st.split("\n")

print lst
['', '', '', 'asd', '']

print lst[1][-1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-82ba25ef865c> in <module>()
----> 1 print lst[1][-1]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

My remedy for solving this would be a ternary expression

**code:**

```
print lst[1][-1] if len(lst[1])>0 else "None"
```

**In your case:**

```
genome = genome + k_mers_parsed[i][-1] if len(k_mers_parsed[i])>0 else " "
```